# How to ensure NSAlert pop up on window top?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

The application is background only

This is a timer app

A dialog box(NSAlert) pops up after a specified time to prompt the user. How to ensure NSAlert on window top?

StatusBarMenu

```swift
class StatusBarMenu: NSObject {
    
    private let statusItem: NSStatusItem!

    init(statusItem: NSStatusItem) {
        self.statusItem = statusItem
    }
    
    private func createMenu() {
        selft.addMenuItem()
    }
    
    func refresh() {
        self.statusItem.menu?.removeAllItems()
        self.createMenu()
    }

    func addMenuItem() {
        let item = NSMenuItem(title: "show alert", action: #selector(self.showAlert), keyEquivalent: "")
        item.target = self
        self.statusItem.menu?.addItem(item)
    }
    
    @objc func showAlert() {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.icon = NSImage(named: "Alert")
            alert.messageText = title
            alert.informativeText = text
            alert.alertStyle = .informational
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "ok")
            alert.runModal()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to provide some code to be able to check it and help

Comment: You can not keep a window always on top anymore on macOS. It is been like that for a while already. You would need a third party app to modify your system, it can not be built into your app. All you can do is set a window level to `.floating` which is already the default of an alert.

Comment: “You can not keep a window always on top anymore on macOS” Really @LeoDabus? LittleSnitch does it. Carbon Copy Cloner does it. And so on.

Comment: Just `alert.window.level = .floating` it works

Comment: @user12932883 it is not the same as always on top. To achieve always on top while others apps are active you would need to add an observer to monitor when the application resign active and set the window level again.

Comment: @user12932883 I haven't tested it in a status menu

Comment: Yes, my question expression is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question:

`alert.window.level = .floating`

This works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to keep NSAlert window on top

```
alert = NSAlert.alertWithMessageText_defaultButton_alternateButton_otherButton_informativeTextWithFormat_(
    title, ok, cancel, other, message)
alert.setAlertStyle_(0)  # informational style
# customize# floating window
alert.window().setLevel_(3)
```